# How do I store access token in Asp NET core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, storage, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 API that has to connect to another external API. To make requests to this API, it needs an OAuth 2 access token so i need to store to reuse it until it runs out and request another one if needed.

So which is the best option to store it?

I've read about using a custom class to use an static `HttpClient` but it doesn't work for what i have to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft choose one of best way for this.

[image]

and you can save on your database.

Comment: I think this could be the best option but, how can i know the lifetime of the token? I should take it from database everytime i have to do a request  and update the data when i getUnauthorize response?

Comment: I've tried to save the token on my database but now i have the problema that is not a common user the one who is making the request, is a background procces so i have no UserId related to AspNetUsers when the token is requested.

Comment: check your life token on Authentication process. if it expired request for refresh token and save in database again.

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing that. Thanks a lot for your answer, u saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

if your project has a database just make a table with property token and
expire time and if it doesn't save these in a text file
(search about working with system.io) but it's better to use a database

Comment: As i ask to @thisisnabi  I should take it from database everytime i have to do a request and update the data when i getUnauthorize response?

Answer (score 1):

You can write token to your database if your project has connection to db, or you have other options like writing to a static variable, cache or file.